# Javascript tied to link_to is being executed on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ujs

I have an index page that loads a bunch of records.  Each record has a "favorite" icon.  Clicking "favorite" sends a `POST` to the server and reloads the page.

I'm trying to use jQuery (ujs??) for the `POST`.

Controller action now looks like this:

```
      def favorite
        @record = Record.find(params[:id])
        @record.toggle_flag("favorite")
      end
```

The favorite icon is being rendered with a partial on the `index` view and is a `link_to`:

```
    <%= link_to(
      icon,
      path,
      method: :post,
      remote: true
    ) %>
```

The `app/views/records/favorite.js.erb` file looks like this:

```
    console.log("I am executing");
    $("[data-id='icon']").update("<%= j render 'icon', { icon: @record.favorite_icon, path: favorite_record_path } %>");
```

When I try and load `index`, I get an error stating that @record is nil.  But why is the JS being executed when loading `index`?  Also, the console log is getting fired right away when loading `index`.  I want the JS to execute on clicking the favorite icon.

Comment: use `$("[data-id='icon']").click()` handler, not `update`

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Tried that just now.  It still executes right away and tells me I have no @record.  Interestingly, if I go to a completely different route in the app, it will load and not throw a JS error.  So it's just when loading `index` that I get the error.

Comment: mmm, because you rendering some `<%= j render 'icon', { icon: @record.favorite_icon, path: favorite_listing_path } %>` and accesing `@record` for it when script file is rendered?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Your code seems to me perfect and it should work without such errors. It seems like some other js code trigger link click event on page load. So try search for that as well.

Comment: Your method is post so it won't get fire on page load so try put debugger in your favorite action and see it really get fired or not. Might be it only changing your icon code not executing.

Comment: when you open `index` page what happens? i guess, browser tries to load `favorite.js`. where that `js` come from? i guess, from rendering `app/views/records/favorite.js.erb`? what code executes on it's render? `@record.favorite_icon`. Browser requires the jscript, script is rendered in `erb`, and `erb` calls for unexistent @record, right?

Comment: favorite.js.erb this will execute only on js request not on html request and page load is html request.

Comment: but where you doing that request (js, i mean)?

Comment: As @Dipak said, it seems like some other JS is triggering this action (perhaps some code that ends up clicking on the link via jQuery or something like that). Have you tried isolating the page by removing / commenting out any JS that runs on that page and seeing if the controller action still gets executed on page load?

Comment: @Dipak, you were right.  I had stupidly put the same JS in `assets/javascripts/records/favorite.js.erb and it was what was really firing.  If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to me perfect and it should work without such errors. It seems like some other js code trigger link click event on page load. So try search for that as well.

`favorite.js.erb` will execute only on js request not on html request and page load is html request.

So try find js code that firing click event.

Comment: Thanks again!  I mistakenly put the same JS in `assets/javascripts/records/favorite.js.erb and it was what was really firing.  On another note, there was a typo in my original JS and it was not loading/executing because of that (there were no console errors to warn me).  I went down many other rabbit holes before going back and finding the typo.  Lesson learned:  write simple JS first to see if the file is loading and getting executed.